# add custom tab to customer adminhtml screen

Tags: adminhtml

I know this has been asked so many times before however I more so have a question.

I am copying the file

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php
```

and putting it in

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php
```

I then edit the `Tabs.php` to have a `new tab` however when I refresh my screen, I even logged out cleared my cache and logged back in Magento does not seem to read from the `app/code/local/mage` directory?

However if I make the same changes in the file located in the core folder my changes work? So why can I not more the file to the local file?

I am using `Magento CE 1.9.1.0` 
Shouldn't I be able to copy any file into the local directory and as long as the folder structure is the same it should load it??

Answer (score 5):

I think none of the other answers (at this time) does it 'the Magento way'. To know how to do it the Magento way, have a look at Magento's Billing Agreements. It adds a tab to the customer edit page as well.

First, `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml`:

```
<adminhtml_customer_edit>
    <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
        <action method="addTab"><name>customer_edit_tab_agreements</name><block>sales/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_agreement</block></action>
        ....
    </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_edit>
```

Now you wonder: I have no title or content! No problem. Have a look at the above referenced block `Mage_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Agreement` (in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Agreement.php`). I don't think it's useful to copy/paste the entire file here, but all the magic is there, like `getTabLabel()`, `getTabTitle()` and `canShowTab()`. It extends `Mage_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Billing_Agreement_Grid` because there's a grid in it, but you could also extend the more general `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget`.

You didn't mention the use of your tab, but you can even create a whole layout and then reference it by name:

```
<adminhtml_customer_edit>
    <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
        <block type="my_module/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_nameoftab" name="mytab">
            ... add some blocks here ...
        </block>
        <action method="addTab"><name>mytab</name><block>mytab</block></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_edit>
```

So here's what you need to do:

- create your own module (you've probably already done that)
- create a layout file in the adminhtml area to add the tab, specifying the block class
- create the block in your module and create the functions required by the interface (`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface`)

No need for event observers, no need for local overrides, no need for editing the core!

Answer (score 2):

Override the file /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php,

Inside _beforeToHtml() method, add the following code:

```
$this->addTab('Custom',array(
    'label' =>Mage::helper('customer')->__('Custom'),
    'class' =>   'ajax',
    'url'   =>   $this->getUrl('*/*/custom',array('_current'=>true)),
));
```

Override the file /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php,

Add the following code:

```
public function customAction()
{
    $this->_initCustomer();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('modulename/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_custom','admin.customer.custom')->setCustomerId(Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
        ->setUseAjax(true)
        ->toHtml()
    );
}
```

Override the file /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php,

```
public function customAction()
{
    $this->_initCustomer();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('modulename/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_custom','admin.customer.custom')->setCustomerId(Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
        ->setUseAjax(true)
        ->toHtml()
    );
}
```

Create the file /app/code/core/Namespace/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/ and create Custom.php,

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Custom extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('modulename/customer/tab/custom.phtml');
    }
}
```

Now, you need to create a template file.

Go to /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/modulename/customer/tab/ and create custom.phtml,

Write your code here.

Please visit link for more methods to add custom TAB.

http://www.nextbits.eu/blog/how-to-add-tab-in-customer-information-in-magento-admin/

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

Add new custom tab in the Magento Customer Grid by overriding it in our custom module.

To override magento customer grid go to your custom module **config.xml**

```
<config>
 <global>
  <blocks>
   <adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
   <customer_edit_tabs>Stack_modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs</customer_edit_tabs>
    </rewrite>
   </adminhtml>
  </blocks>
 </global>
</config>
```

2. Create a file tabs.php at following path

> app/code/local/Webkul/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/

3. Copy the entire code from this file

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/tabs.php
>
> to your tabs.php
>   (app/code/local/Webkul/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/)

4. Add this code to create new tab

> $this->addTab('payment', array( 'label' =>
>   Mage::helper('customer')->__('Payment Mode'), 'content' =>
>   $this->paymentmode(), ));

```
protected function _beforeToHtml() {  
  if (Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId()) 
        {
         $this->addTab('payment', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('customer')->__('Payment Mode'),
                'content'=> $this->paymentmode(),
            ));    
         }
       }
```

**/*note: in 'content' you can pass a string or function*/**

/* write these line after completion of  function

**protected function _beforeToHtml(){}**

```
protected function paymentmode()
{ 
 return 'Your content Come Here';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't I be able to copy any file into the local directory and as
>   long as the folder structure is the same it should load it?

No, not if you have compilation enabled. Look at top of /app/Mage.php

- Check in backend for 'Compilation' is disabled (Or re-compile).
- Check /includes/Config.php, if everything is commented out.

Good luck with overriding Magento Core Files.

Ps: Magento is configuration based and **event driven** system.

```
<adminhtml>
    ...
    <events>
       <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
            <observers>
                <[namespace]_[module]_product>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>[module]/adminhtml_observer</class>
                    <method>addProductTabBlock</method>
                </[namespace]_[module]_product>
            </observers>
       </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
    </events>
    ....
</adminhtml>
```